# How do you approach scroll-based animations when scroll wheel or mobile is involved?

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, user-experience, gsap

I made a LP with scroll animations I'm really proud of. BUT it only looks good when used with a trackpad on a lap/desktop. With a mousewheel it's no longer smooth, and on a mobile devices the alignment breaks when the address bar (etc) changes the viewport height.

This is probably a common issue with animations. How do you guys handle it? Is there a best practice?

Comment: It might be a better idea to include the code you've made and make an interactive example by reading [How do I create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now we don't know what you are seeing and what the end result should be.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Not in this case. I'm not looking to solve a specific issue with my code. I'm looking to learn how someone with experience would handle this. Address bar changing viewport height is normal behaviour. Mouse wheel scrolling in increments is also normal. I'm just looking to learn how seasoned FE devs make beautiful scroll animations. Maybe someone here wrote up a blog post on this, or read a medium article or something?

Comment: I guess if someone did then searching for it on the web would give you the results that you are looking for. I would still suggest that you include your code and let a seasoned FE look at it. Or checkout [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is a community about evaluating code and they might give you some tips. Otherwise your question is off-topic will eventually be closed.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier googling is the first thing I do. Mostly to avoid the knee-jerk "just search for it" replies that guardians of the sanctity of the SO community are so fond of throwing out. Luckily you're not one of those. I will check out codereview. Thanks for that tip. And, if you feel you have a clever solution to common scroll animation issues that would trip up a novice like me, you might consider that this is the place to share it ;-)

Comment: Add smooth scrolling. ScrollTrigger has [a .scrollerProxy() method](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.scrollerProxy()) to allow you to hook up a smooth scrolling library to it.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thank you! I'll experiment with that.